# How to read all files in Android/media directory including folders with a .nomedia file programmatically in Android 11

Tags: android, media, file-access, android-11

I want read files in Android/media/x.com/.dir without using All file access permission in android 11.
`x.com` is not the my app's package name, `.dir` is a another app's media directory. Also it contains `.nomedia` file. So is it possible to read files in `.dir` directory. I know that we can do it with `MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission. But it is difficult to publish app with this permission in PlayStore and also my app only need to access files in media directory. The problem is that folder which I want read contains a `.nomedia` file. Is there any way to do that without `MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission.